# Necessary mass and speed of asteroid required to make Venus spin

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, orbital-motion, estimation, planets

Suppose we are going to push a large asteroid (or two) from the belt and use them to make Venus rotate at approximately the same rotational speed as earth. Here are some questions regarding that:

1. If we were to keep the same orbit, would we need to hit the planet simultaneously with two meteors (one on each side traveling in opposite directions)?
2. Or if the intent was to make it rotate and move it slightly further from the sun, could you do that in a single hit?
3. Do we have asteroids of the necessary size in the belt at present?
4. And some mechanism to make one fall in a way that it would achieve sufficient momentum?
5. Exactly how much mass and momentum/acceleration would we need to make this happen?
6. What can go wrong with this plan? (And should we consult Marco Inaros?)

Comment: For readers whose science-fiction consumption is behind the times, the reference to Marco Inaros is a mild spoiler for “The Expanse.”

Comment: Suppose we have appropriate asteroids in the asteroid belt. You would have to push on them pretty hard to direct them at Venus at the right speed and direction. Why not push on Venus instead?

Comment: Hi Brannon. Welcome to Phys.SE. Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope-calculation?

Comment: What Qm said. All these plans require a  very large amount of energy. What energy source(s) do you have in mind, and how do you intend to harmess that energy?

Comment: @Qmechanic, I wish that I had the training necessary to compute this. I think I could do a computation for making a pendulum spin, but I have no experience with free-body physics. Obviously I don't need the calculation -- it was posted for fun.

Comment: @PM2Ring, we have to start with just a little energy, with some boosters on an asteroid, or a nearby nuclear explosion. The additional momentum would be achieved via gravity assist from other planets and the sun.

Comment: @mmesser314, the reason for using asteroids was to gain additional energy through gravity-assist (aka, slingshot) from the sun or other planets. Pushing on a planet directly seems hard, especially when it has a cruel atmosphere, and we lack a really large lever. How would you push on it directly? I'm curious now.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to pour cold water on idea 2 - presumably with the intent of cooling Venus for life - along the lines @mmesser314 noted, but to give Venus an orbit much wider than its current one means adding energy on the order of $GMm/a$, while changing its transverse momentum on the order of $m\sqrt{GM/a}$, which will require an impactor mass on the order of $m$, and Venus has thousands of times the mass of the asteroid belt.

Idea 1 is much more modest: Venus only needs to gain $\frac15mR^2\omega^2\approx2\times10^{29}\operatorname{J}$ rotational KE. Life on Venus would require changing the atmosphere, and one proposal for this requires [a hydrogen payload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraforming_of_Venus#Introduction_of_hydrogen) of about $10^{19}\operatorname{kg}$ (barely a hundredth the mass of Ceres), which could adjust the rotation as desired if delivered at a few hundred $\operatorname{km/s}$. In fact, some proposals [*wouldn't*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraforming_of_Venus#Arguments_for_keeping_the_current_day-night_cycle_unchanged) speed up Venus's rotation, but that's another story.